# Перенос слова "государств"

Tags: орфография, перенос

В связи с возникшим спором в школе между учителем и учеником, прошу Вас разъяснить правильность переноса слова ГОСУДАРСТВ.
Вариант ученика ГОСУДАР-СТВ признан неверным. Увы, объяснить, почему такой перенос невозможен, учитель не смог.
Разъясните, пожалуйста, правильный вариант переноса слова!

Answer (score 4):

Не разрешается оставлять на строке или переносить в следующую строку буквенную цепочку, не содержащую гласной буквы (В. В. Лопатин). Го-су-дарств - правильный перенос слова.

Comment: А почему вы делите на слоги слово? Говорится ведь  о переносе, а о не разделении на слоги.

Comment: *А почему вы делите на слоги слово?* - ???

Comment: Извините, автоматически. Хотела написать: го-сударств, госу-дарств.

Comment: *Извините, автоматически. Хотела написать: го-сударств, госу-дарств.* - нормально Вы все сделали. Такое сокращение общепринято, за чем писать дважды, ясно же что это два варианта. Надо быть Сержем, чтобы придраться.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать.

Comment: Я не  behemothus,чтобы придираться, я  все лишь спросил.

Comment: А я не Серж, чтобы придирки называть вопросами.

Answer (score 2):

> ...правильность переноса слова ГОСУДАРСТВ.

Правильно: ***го-су-дарств.***

> Вариант ученика ГОСУДАР-СТВ признан неверным.

Да, такой вариант переноса противоречит правилам.

[**См.:**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97)

> **§ 212.** Не разрешается оставлять на строке или переносить в следующую строку буквенную цепочку, не содержащую гласной буквы.
>   Напр., нельзя переносить: ***cm-вол, вс-лед, цен-тр, тре-ст.***

Answer (score 2):

Ну собственно, ответили все. Есть несколько формулировок этого правила, мне кажется, что смысла как-то улучшать известное с незапамятных времен *"На каждой строчке должна быть хоть одна гласная буква переносимого слова"* и нету. Просто и со вкусом. § 212 - рулит.

На всякий случай: современные правила переноса очень либеральны и по сути сводятся к выше упомянутому правилу и еще двум:

*"На каждой строчке должно быть минимум две буквы"*,
*"Запрещается делать перенос в месте между согласной и гласной буквой (в указанном порядке, Й считается согласной) и между согласной и мягким и твердым знаком"*.

Остальное касается особых случаев (дефиса, например) и не особо актуально.

В чем тут могла запутаться учительница - трудно сказать...

Answer (score 1):

Учитель прав: такой перенос неправильный. По правилам не разрешается оставлять на строке или переносить в следующую строку буквенную цепочку, не содержащую гласной буквы. Напр., нельзя переносить: cт-вол, вс-лед, цен-тр, тре-ст.

[См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97)